# Unable to read text file in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a local text file present in the location /home/myname/Desktop/iot/public/sensordata.txt. This file has to be read in JavaScript when a button is clicked on a web page. My code is given below:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Humidity</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>Humidity page</h3>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" onclick="humidgraph('public/sensordata.txt','chartContainer')">View live humidity data</button> 
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <p><div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px;width= 100%;"></div></p>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function humidgraph(datasource,divid){

                var i=0;
                var xVal,yVal;
                var humidity=[],time=[],dps=[];
                var fileread=false;
                var obj=document.getElementById(divid);

                if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
                    fileread=new XMLHttpRequest();
                }else if(window.ActiveXObject){
                    fileread=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }

                if(fileread){
                    fileread.open("GET",datasource);
                    document.getElementById("chartContainer").innerHTML=fileread.responseText;
                }
                fileread.onreadystatechange=function(){

                    if((fileread.readyState===4 || fileread.readyState===0) && fileread.status===200){

                        var text=fileread.responseText;
                        text.split(/\n/).forEach(function(item){
                            humidity.push(Number(item.match(/Humidity(.\d+[.]\d+)/)[1]));
                        });
                        text.split(/\n/).forEach(function(item){
                            time.push(Number(item.match(/time(.\d+[.]\d+)/)[1]));
                        });
                    }
                }

                while(i<time.length){
                    xVal=time[i];
                    yVal=humidity[i];
                    dps.push({x: xVal,y: yVal});
                    i++;
                }

            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

However, no data is being printed on the html page, even though innerHTML is being used. Is there something wrong with my file path? Please help.

Comment: You probably get a warning/ error in your console saying you are not allowed to view that file.

Comment: No, I did not get any such warning/error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run a webserver and make the get request to a URI on that server, rather than making the get request to a file (you get a "cross origin requests" error).

Then change:

```
humidgraph('public/sensordata.txt','chartContainer')
```

to read something like:

```
humidgraph('http://localhost/public/sensordata.txt','chartContainer')
```

and the initial request page needs to be loaded from that server as well.

Additionally you should do your request in the below order:

```
fileread.onreadystatechange=function (){
   ...
};
...

fileread.open("GET", datasource);
fileread.send();
```